# French equivalents of the colloquial German "abdrücken" in the sense of "paying a sum of money"

Tags: allemand

In conversation, we were talking about paying an extra five euros for an Olympic ticket, and I said jokingly:

> Du kannst nich‘ mal fünf lausige Euro **abdrücken**? Tja, juckt mich auch nich‘ weiter.

- {in the sense of: "5 Euro drauflegen"}

The "abdrücken" has the fundamental meaning of "squeezing something/someone", "squeezing the trigger". The verb is also used colloquially in the sense of "paying a sum of money / laying out money".

> ≈ T’as même pas cinq misérables euros à me **lâcher** ? Bah, ça m’est égal.

The verb "lâcher" came to mind, though I cannot seem to find a dictionary entry for this specific usage. So I'm not sure if my phrasing above works well enough to convey this idea. In informal, colloquial language, how is this idea commonly expressed in French?

Comment: Your exemple is good, I would use the same sentence in a daily conversation.

Answer (score 2):

*lâcher* is fine, but I would use it without *me* that gives the idea that the money's given or lent to you, which is not there in the German original, otherwise, you might wanna say :

- T’as même pas cinq misérables euros à me filer ? Bah, ça m’est égal.
- T’as même pas cinq misérables euros à me refiler ? Bah, ça m’est égal.

You could also use *cracher* which has the added meaning that you're unwilling to pay.  I would use a different structure though.

- Tu peux pas cracher cinq euros!

*allonger* is ok too :

- Tu peux pas allonger cinq euros!

Comment: Hi. I wasn't familiar with this particular usage of "refiler". Is it generally used in a money-giving context like this?

Comment: Not necessarily, you could say "il m'a refilé sa crève" to mean "I caught a cold from him", "il m'a refilé un vieux bureau"," he gave me an old desk"…

Comment: Refiler (as indicated by the "cold" usage) has slight negative connotation, the implication being that the giver is basically *getting rid* of the item (cf. "refiler un problème", meaning "unload it off [on someone]")